# Confused on redoing CRUD after linking to mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud, mlab

I have a basic CRUD app that loads blog posts from my local mongo database, and they are rendered to an html page. CRUD operations worked until I started loading api data from mlab. Although GET function works, I don't know how to go about getting DELETE, PUT, and POST to work. I know it should be simple, I just need a pointer in the right direction.

My previous work using my local database is commented out in server.js and models.js, since I still want to retain that code.

Sorry, forgot to add the link to my github: https://github.com/maria-S-456/final-node-blog

Comment: We can rule out connection issue if your GET function works. How is your mlab user set up ? does the user only have read role ?  What do you see when you make other calls ?

Comment: It has read/write permissions. Other calls say "could not get any response"

Answer (score 0):

On your server.js you forgot to change `<username>:<password>` to the mongodb user's UN/PW on line 5. Also, I don't think you need a port variable as that's included in the mongodb connection string.

Edit: Just be careful about what you use for your password as github is completely open to anyone to see if this is going to be live code it wouldn't be hard to inject whatever they want into your DB. If this is live consider using [DotEnv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: That was intentional, since I was posting on github. On my local machine, I do include password and username.